# Environment variable and docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When running a number of linked services with `docker-compose up`, how can I add values for environment variables to be passed to specific containers for services? Say I have a service "webapp" which uses the TIMEOUT environment variable, how do I set TIMEOUT=10000 with docker-compose for the container that "webapp" lives in? I have tried the notation `-e TIMEOUT=10000` from the `docker` command, but this does not seem to work.

Comment: for me it works `$ docker run -it -e abc=turlututu ubuntu env` shows 
`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=dabbf551b167
TERM=xterm
abc=turlututu
HOME=/root
`

Answer (score 2):

with docker compose your have to specify environment variables in `docker-compose.yml` with `env_file` or `environment` configuration commands

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env-file
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment